# How to sample large texture in OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

I am now trying to use a fragment shader to process images on a texture. However, I found that only 10 bits float is supported by the fragment shader so when the length of the screen is 1280 pixels, I failed to get the value stored in the pixel because it is impossible for me to use 10 bits to sample 1280 pixels.

I am wondering how can I get the pixel on a large texture accurately?

Comment: What proof do you have that some GLSL-capable hardware only provides 10 bits of accuracy? And what hardware is this?

Comment: I checked the device using the function glGetShaderPrecisionFormat to test the support of GLES20.GL_HIGH_FLOAT but than found that it is not supported by the hardware. And it means that the precision of highp is not supported by the device. More details of the function can be found in http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetShaderPrecisionFormat.xml @NicolBolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 different precision formats for floats. [OpenGL ES Shading Language reference](http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf) says:

1. `highp`: 16-bit, floating point range: -2^62 to 2^62, integer range:
   -2^16 to 2^16
2. `mediump`: 10-bit, floating point range: -2^14 to 2^14, integer
   range: -2^10 to 2^10
3. `lowp`: 8-bit, floating point range: -2 to 2, integer range: -2^8 to
   2^8

To be able to sample from >1024x1024 texture you have to switch the precision to `highp` by placing the following code at the beginning of your `GLSL` program.

```
precision highp float;
```

Comment: In fact I have tried it but I found that the precision of highp is not supported by the device. The support for this precision is optional. So most GPU of mobile devices do not support this precision for fragment shader because usually a texture of this size is thought to be unnecessary. Thus even if this line of code is added to the beginning of the program, I still failed to sample the texture. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the size of the texture to 1024 or to split it into several textures?

Comment: In fact I am now trying to split it into several textures. But I am afraid spliting textures will have negative effect on the efficiency of the program. I once tried to reduce the size of the texture but I found that a texture of the size 1024 is also too large. I still do not know the cause of the problem. Thank you @Sergey K.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me and I will accept it now. But I am still afraid that spliting the texture will result in a loss of efficiency. @Sergey K.

Comment: It seems like it is the best choice.